# Need help to correct my swing application output

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, graphics2d

I am trying to make an application which typically demonstrates the src_in AlphaComposite.The output which i require is:-

[image]

But i am getting the following output:-
[image]

Where am i doing mistake? Here is the full code of mine.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class SrcInDemo extends JFrame{
private JCheckBox jcb;
SrcInDemo()
{
super("SrcIn Demonstration");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(600,600);

add(new comp(),BorderLayout.CENTER);

setVisible(true);
add(jcb=new JCheckBox("Shadow"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
jcb.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        repaint();
    }});
}
class comp extends JComponent
{
private BufferedImage image,landscape;
comp()
{
    try{
    image=ImageIO.read(/*getClass().getResource("picture.png")*/new File("src/picture.png"));
    landscape=ImageIO.read(/*getClass().getResource("landscape.jpg")*/new File("src/landscape.jpg"));
    }catch(IOException e){System.out.printf("error loading image");}
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
//The following commented lines were there in the original code of Filthy Rich Clients
//But I have removed them as it was supposed to create a back image.I have created  g2 
//directly.
            /* BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = temp.createGraphics();*/

    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g.create();
    if(jcb.isSelected())
    {
        int x=(getWidth()-image.getWidth())/2;
        int y=(getHeight()-image.getHeight())/2;
        g2.drawImage(image,x+4,y+4,null);

        Composite oldComposite=g2.getComposite();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        g2.setComposite(oldComposite);
        g2.drawImage(image,x,y,null);
    }
    else
    {
        int x=(getWidth()-image.getWidth())/2;
        int y=(getHeight()-image.getHeight())/2;
        g2.drawImage(image,x,y,null);
        Composite oldComposite=g2.getComposite();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcIn);
        g2.drawImage(landscape,x,y,null);
        g2.setComposite(oldComposite);
    }
            //g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);
}
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){new SrcInDemo();}});
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not in front of PC to try, but I suspect that the composite should be applied at the second stage of rendering

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the examples from Filthy Rich Clients and run the examples and have no issue.  Given that your code is identical, I would suggest that problem is with your images.

Alpha composites work on the alpha channel of the images.

For example, if I alter the shield image to look like...(Red with 50% alpha)

[image]

I end up with...

[image]

Comment: :I have added some lines as comments in above code which were there in the original code of Filthy Rich Clients but I removed them.However,i don't remove them and run ,then it works fine.
But why?Those lines are meant for back image only,for double buffering.(Please see edited code)

Comment: ***I Have posted 1 answer please check it and let me have ur suggestions***

And a small ques wrt that answer:-Is there any other way to get same 

effect of  TYPE_INT_ARGB on graphics2D object instead of 

creating BufferedImage.Like what if i already had g2 

object and now later at some time i want to set 

TYPE_INT_ARGB on it.

BTW in my opinion TYPE_INT_ARGB is defined for image and 

it has nothing to do with g2 so there should not be any 

way.

Comment: You can't change the graphics object the fly (making it TYPE_ARG). You can clear a component graphics with a transparent color, but it won't work the same with graphics coming from a buffered image that isn't transparent

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after a long study and search i have found a solution to my problem.Please correct if am wrong.Here we go:-

TYPE_INT_ARGB is used in case of images that have a transparent background.TYPE_INT_ARGB tells our program that our image has a transparent background.If we do not use it then the image is considered as a rectangle (white background+image).That is why in my program the landscape image appeared outside the shield image also.Actually it was not outside the shield image,but it was within as now the shield image is considered as a rectangle image(shield+white background).Same was the reason for black background in shadow case.Hence I must use TYPE_INT_ARGB.